# How exclude directory from WebPack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I'm using Storybook to develop a React component. The documentation of an SDK I'm importing in my app says to include a folder '.storybook/src/cards/myCard/xSDK' but not to bundle it.

I'm making the SDK call like this: importedSdkCall({SDKFolderPath: './xSDK'}). The folder is in the same directory as the component making the call.

I'm getting: 404 - http://localhost:6006/xSDK/x2.bundle.js

Storybook allows me to manipulate the generated webpack.config file. Here's the rules array from that file:

````
"rules": [
  {
    "test": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
        "options": {
          "cacheDirectory": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/.cache/storybook/babel",
          "sourceType": "unambiguous",
          "presets": [
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js",
              {
                "shippedProposals": true,
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/preset-typescript/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js",
              {
                "runtime": "automatic"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-flow/lib/index.js"
          ],
          "plugins": [
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/index.js",
              {
                "legacy": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true,
                "useBuiltIns": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-parameters/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-spread/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-for-of/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/lib/index.js",
              {
                "method": "usage-global",
                "absoluteImports": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/core-js/index.js",
                "version": "3.15.2"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-add-react-displayname/index.js"
          ],
          "overrides": [
            {
              "test": {},
              "plugins": [
                [
                  "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-docgen/lib/index.js",
                  {
                    "DOC_GEN_COLLECTION_NAME": "STORYBOOK_REACT_CLASSES"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "include": [
      "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library"
    ],
    "exclude": {}
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
        "options": {
          "sourceType": "unambiguous",
          "presets": [
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js",
              {
                "shippedProposals": true,
                "modules": false,
                "loose": true,
                "targets": "defaults"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js"
          ],
          "plugins": [
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/index.js",
              {
                "legacy": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true,
                "useBuiltIns": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-parameters/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-spread/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-for-of/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/lib/index.js",
              {
                "method": "usage-global",
                "absoluteImports": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/core-js/index.js",
                "version": "3.15.2"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "include": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
        "options": {
          "presets": [
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js",
              {
                "modules": "commonjs"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
        "options": {
          "babelrc": false,
          "configFile": false,
          "cacheDirectory": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/.cache/storybook/babel",
          "sourceType": "unambiguous",
          "presets": [
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js",
              {
                "shippedProposals": true,
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/preset-typescript/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js",
              {
                "runtime": "automatic"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-flow/lib/index.js"
          ],
          "plugins": [
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/index.js",
              {
                "legacy": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true,
                "useBuiltIns": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-parameters/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-spread/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-for-of/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/lib/index.js",
              {
                "method": "usage-global",
                "absoluteImports": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/core-js/index.js",
                "version": "3.15.2"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-add-react-displayname/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/index.js",
              {
                "pragma": "React.createElement",
                "pragmaFrag": "React.Fragment"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "overrides": [
            {
              "test": {},
              "plugins": [
                [
                  "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-docgen/lib/index.js",
                  {
                    "DOC_GEN_COLLECTION_NAME": "STORYBOOK_REACT_CLASSES"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@mdx-js/loader/index.js",
        "options": {
          "compilers": [
            null
          ],
          "remarkPlugins": [
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "exclude": {},
    "use": [
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
        "options": {
          "babelrc": false,
          "configFile": false,
          "cacheDirectory": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/.cache/storybook/babel",
          "sourceType": "unambiguous",
          "presets": [
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js",
              {
                "shippedProposals": true,
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/preset-typescript/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js",
              {
                "runtime": "automatic"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/preset-flow/lib/index.js"
          ],
          "plugins": [
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators/lib/index.js",
              {
                "legacy": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js",
              {
                "loose": true,
                "useBuiltIns": true
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-parameters/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-spread/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-for-of/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js",
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator/lib/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3/lib/index.js",
              {
                "method": "usage-global",
                "absoluteImports": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/core-common/node_modules/core-js/index.js",
                "version": "3.15.2"
              }
            ],
            "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-add-react-displayname/index.js",
            [
              "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/index.js",
              {
                "pragma": "React.createElement",
                "pragmaFrag": "React.Fragment"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "overrides": [
            {
              "test": {},
              "plugins": [
                [
                  "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-docgen/lib/index.js",
                  {
                    "DOC_GEN_COLLECTION_NAME": "STORYBOOK_REACT_CLASSES"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@mdx-js/loader/index.js",
        "options": {
          "remarkPlugins": [
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/cjs/index.js",
    "options": {
      "injectStoryParameters": true,
      "inspectLocalDependencies": true
    },
    "enforce": "pre"
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "sideEffects": true,
    "use": [
      "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js",
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js",
        "options": {
          "importLoaders": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js",
        "options": {
          "postcssOptions": {
            "config": false,
            "plugins": [
              null,
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js",
    "options": {
      "esModule": false,
      "name": "static/media/[path][name].[ext]"
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {},
    "loader": "/Users/christopheroppedal/Repos/experience-library/node_modules/url-loader/dist/cjs.js",
    "options": {
      "limit": 10000,
      "name": "static/media/[path][name].[ext]"
    }
  }
] ```
````

Comment: use `"exclude": { module or package name to exclude }`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing to a create-react-app project and moving the bundled SDK into the /public directory.